# Can a condition for a global maximum (of some specific function) be given?

Tags: calculus, probability, optimization

Suppose we have a twice continuously differentiable function

$h(x) := \frac{g(x)}{1 - \delta + \delta F(x)}$, $0<\delta<1$, defined on the interval $[0, a]$ (where $a$ may be infinite). The function has a local maximum at some known $x^* \in (0,a)$.

Importantly, $F(x)$ is a cumulative distribution function that has a *strictly quasi-concave* probability density function $F'(x)$, defined on the interval $[0,a]$, with $\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx = 1$.

I am wondering whether there are any simple conditions on $g(x)$ and $\delta$ which guarantee that $x^*$ is a global maximizer on $[0,a]$. Does anybody recall any helpful theorems?

As always, any help is greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you accept as help also examples of such $h$ and $g$? Have you a particular quasi concave function in mind?

Comment: Actually, I realized that I made a mistake when formulating the problem. See the updated text for what I am actually interested in.

Comment: Density functions I am interested in could be the Log-normal distribution, Gamma distribution, Weibull distribution, Log-logistic distribution, but also any other pdf that is strictly quasi-concave.